# Qt model/view vs standard widget

Tags: qt, qtableview, qtablewidget, qtreeview, qtreewidget

I am currently reading model/view [tutorial](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/modelview.html) from Qt, but I am still not sure if I should use model/view or widget for my Qt program :

I need to do a logger application that will monitor all information in a simulation environment.  Basic scenario might be :

1. *User 1* say something to *virtual entity B*  (logger application get what user 1 said and show it in table view or list view)
2. *Virtual entity B* reply something to *user 1* (logger application get what user 1 said and add it in table view or list view)

etc

The needs of this logger application is to get this information in real time and also, the data collected will NOT be editable.  Essentially, this is just to show logs.

So, is it worth it to use modal/view or widget is enough for what I want to do?

Thank you

Comment: I'd say go with widgets, some signals goodies and you're good to go, no need to over engineering with model/view.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had simular target and simular question. I looked both solutions.

I created log file with 20 mb size. Then, I loaded him into QTableView with own model, and to QTableWidget with standard model.

QTableView was more faster (about 30 sec) than QTableWidget (about 1.5 min), but solution with QTableWidget was easer.

About you question i think, if you will have big log (many information must be loaded immediately), you should use QTableView with own model. Else more easer is use QTableWidget with standard model.

Answer (score 1):

If the logs entries are not saved in a database table, go with the widgets, otherwise I would give a look at the model/view